# D3 to Append Inputs of Desired Type

Tags: javascript, d3.js

First consider how easy it is to populate a drop down menu with D3:

```
var options = [
        "option 1",
        "option 2",
        "option 3",
        "option 4"
    ];
    d3.select("#my_select")
        .selectAll("option")
        .data(options)
        .enter().append("option")
        .attr("value", function(d) { return d; })
        .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

However, I'm not quite sure how I can append an HTML user input that is not already preexisting, and it also doesn't need to be 'populated' with the `data()` call. In my case I simply want to append a number input for the user. I tried this (and many similar variants):

```
graphGroup.append('input')
    .attr('type','number');
```

That didn't work. So I then looked at the pure javascript solution, which looks something like this:

```
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.innerHTML = "New Entry " + " <br><input type='number' name='myInputs[]'>";
  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
```

But, I would hope that d3 has a slightly more elegant solution. The reason being, my input appending needs will surely evolve as I progress with my project. During my research, I have not found a d3 example of this, so I'm really keen on figuring out the d3 approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it directly with d3 like this. I have added both a dropdown and a numberic html input.

```
var options = [
  "option 1",
  "option 2",
  "option 3",
  "option 4"
];

var select = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .append("select");

var input = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
  .append("input")
    .attr("type", "number");

select
  .on("change", function(d) {
    var value = d3.select(this).property("value");
    alert(value);
  });

select.selectAll("option")
  .data(options)
  .enter()
  .append("option")
  .attr("value", function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
```

Check Fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/2k5j5xag/